# VBA Range not working, global parameter?

Tags: database, vba, excel

This is my code as I am trying to apply this formula to a column of data that is continuously changing.

```
Dim x As Integer
x = Range("N3").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNT(C[-10])"
Range("P1").FormulaR1C1 = "Die Type"
Range("P2:Px").FormulaR1C1 = "=RIGHT(LEFT(RC[-12],2),1)"***
```

I keep getting an error 1004 saying "method range object_global failed.

How do I set X as my variable value?

I am using excel 2007.

Answer (score 2):

This is odd, I don't think you can get a count of cells this way:

```
x = Range("N3").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNT(C[-10])"
```

Could you try:

```
Dim x As Integer
x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("D3:N3"))

Range("P1") = "Die Type"
Range("P2:P" & x).FormulaR1C1 = "=RIGHT(LEFT(RC[-12],2),1)"
```

Answer (score 0):

count() only counts numbers
you may need to use counta() if you have text in D3:N3
`x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Counta(Range("D3:N3"))`